# Understanding memory consumption in PonyORM with SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, memory-leaks, orm, ponyorm

I have the following code which loads a large CSV file (more than 3.5 million rows) into a SQLite database.

The program works fine but it seems that it does not free memory so while running the program I can see with command `top` how its memory size grows until it exhaustes all available server memory and the program is killed without inserting all rows.

My understanding is that the included `db.commit()` (which is executed everytime we start loading a new month in the CSV) shall free any Candlestick instances created (which, I presume, are the ones that are making memory grow), but it does not do that.

Why is this happening and what can be corrected in the code to make it work without this memory leak?

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Load CSV Data into SQLite Database

from decimal import *
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

from pony.orm import *
import csv

# Input parameters
csv_filename = 'dax-1m.csv'
csv_timeframe = '1m'
csv_delimiter = ';'
csv_quotechar = '"'
csv_timezone = timezone('America/New_York')
db_filename = 'dax.db'
db_timezone = timezone('Europe/Berlin')

# Open/Create database
db = Database()

# Data Model
class Candlestick(db.Entity):
    timeframe = Required(unicode)
    timestamp = Required(datetime)
    open = Required(Decimal, precision=12, scale=6)
    high = Required(Decimal, precision=12, scale=6)
    low = Required(Decimal, precision=12, scale=6)
    close = Required(Decimal, precision=12, scale=6)
    volume = Required(Decimal, precision=12, scale=6)

db.bind(provider='sqlite', filename=db_filename, create_db=True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)    

# Loader class
class Loader():
    def load(self):
        rowcount = 0;
        current_year = -1;
        current_month = -1;
        with open(csv_filename, newline='') as csvfile:
            r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=csv_delimiter, quotechar=csv_quotechar)
            with db_session:
                for row in r:

                    _year = int(row[0][-4:])
                    _month = int(row[0][3:-5])
                    _day = int(row[0][:2])
                    _hour = int(row[1][:2])
                    _minute = int(row[1][3:5])
                    csv_dt = datetime(_year, _month, _day, _hour, _minute)
                    db_dt = csv_timezone.localize(csv_dt).astimezone(db_timezone)

                    Candlestick(
                        timeframe=db_timezone.zone, 
                        timestamp=db_dt,
                        open=row[2], 
                        high=row[3],
                        low=row[4], 
                        close=row[5],
                        volume=row[6]
                    )

                    rowcount+=1

                    if(_year != current_year or _month != current_month):
                        db.commit()
                        current_year = _year
                        current_month = _month
                        print('Loading data for ' + str(current_year) + ' ' + str(current_month) + ' ...')
                        print('Loaded ' + str(rowcount) + ' registers.')

ldr=Loader()
ldr.load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no memory leak here. Pony clears cache on leaving the db_session scope
here you can see more info on this
https://docs.ponyorm.com/transactions.html#working-with-db-session.

Particularly this one:

When the session ends it does the following actions:

- Clears the Identity Map cache

You need to make the scope of db_session narrower.
Another option is to do commit() after N object creations and then do rollback() for clearing the cache:

```
with db_session(strict=True):
    for i, row in enumerate(r):
        <do some work>
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            commit()  # save the changes
            rollback()  # clear the cache
```

See more info on what happens on rollback() here: https://docs.ponyorm.com/transactions.html#db-session-cache